# BigQueryで取り込んだGAデータのdateを日付型に変えたい

Tags: google-bigquery, google-analytics

以下のような簡単なコードなのですが、dataをcast(data as date) as dateとしてデータ型をStringからDateに変えたいのですが、エラーがでます。解決策をどなたかお教え願えませんか。

```sql
SELECT
  date,
  product.productSKU,
  SUM(totals.pageviews) AS pageview,
  SUM(totals.visits) AS session,
  SUM(totals.transactions) AS transaction,
  COUNT(DISTINCT fullvisitorid) AS user,
  SUM(totals.newvisits) AS newvisits,
  SUM(totals.bounces) AS bounces
FROM
 サンプル.ga_sessions_,
  UNNEST(hits) AS hits,
  UNNEST(hits.product) AS product
WHERE
  _TABLE_SUFFIX BETWEEN FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 6 month))
  AND FORMAT_DATE('%Y%m%d',DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))
GROUP BY
  date,
  product.productSKU
order by date
```

Answer (score 1):

`ga_sessions_` の `date` には `YYYYmmdd` のような形式の文字列が入っており、DATE型として扱えない文字列のため、castしようとするとエラーになります。

そのため、`PARSE_DATE()`などを使用してDATE型に変換する必要があるかと思います。

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/date_functions?hl=ja#parse_date

```sql
SELECT
  date,
  PARSE_DATE('%Y%m%d', date) AS parsed_date
FROM
  UNNEST(
    ARRAY<STRUCT<date STRING>>[
      STRUCT('20200601'),
      STRUCT('20200602'),
      STRUCT('20200603'),
      STRUCT('20200604'),
      STRUCT('20200605'),
      STRUCT('20200606')
    ]
  )
```

`YYYY-mm-dd`のようなDATE型として扱われるような文字列であれば、castによりDATE型へ変換できます。

https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/data-types?hl=ja#date_type

```sql
SELECT
  date,
  DATE_ADD(CAST(date AS DATE), INTERVAL 7 DAY) AS one_week_later
FROM
  UNNEST(
    ARRAY<STRUCT<date STRING>>[
      STRUCT('2020-06-01'),
      STRUCT('2020-06-02'),
      STRUCT('2020-06-03'),
      STRUCT('2020-06-04'),
      STRUCT('2020-06-05'),
      STRUCT('2020-06-06')
    ]
  )
```

Comment: ありがとうございます。そういうことだったのですね。参考になりました。